# How to test EJB method call with Arquillian Weld EE Embedded

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss-weld, jboss-arquillian

I would like to test an EJB, and I want to test it with Weld EE Embedded as I don't want to deploy an applicatoin server for that.

Here is my class :

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class EJBTest {
    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap
                .create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
    }

    @Stateless
    public static class SomeService {
        public String someMethod() {
            return "test";
        }
    }

    @Inject
    SomeService someService;

    @Test
    public void testStatelessCall() {
        Assert.assertEquals("test", someService.someMethod());
    }
}
```

And here are my `pom.xml` dependencies :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-spi</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <!-- version imported with org.jboss.weld:weld-core-bom:1.1.2.Final -->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-container-test-spi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

While testing my class, I've got a NPE :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:195)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at com.mycompany.SomeService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.someMethod(SomeService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at com.mycompany.EJBTest.testStatelessCall(EJBTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:267)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.protocol.local.LocalContainerMethodExecutor.invoke(LocalContainerMethodExecutor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6.evaluate(Arquillian.java:260)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:223)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:311)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:237)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:311)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:196)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
    ... 101 more
```

Does somebody have a solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a Weld EE bug.

See the corresponding [Arquillian forum thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/723563) and [the associated issue on Weld Issue Tracker](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1086).

Answer (score 0):

try use @EJB instead of @Inject.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1', try using 'arquillian-weld-se-embedded-1.1'.
It's a bug indeed and this should fix it.

edit: see you already solved it, my bad :)