# Arquillian injected Weld Bean in EJB is null

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, weld

I am succesfully running EJB tests with Arquillian against an (older) Glassfish 3.1 embedded.

When trying to @Inject weld beans, I get a NPE when I want to address a method in a transitively injected Weld bean.

So, I am testing EJB A. EJB A has a ref to EJB B. EJB B has a ref to a Weld bean.

This is the Jar init.

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "itscool.jar")
            .addClasses(DashboardService.class, PropertyService.class, StorageService.class, EPSRepository.class,
                    EmailService.class, NotificationRepository.class, EmailRepository.class, Configuration.class,
                    MailingList.class, BogusBean.class, Bogus.class)
            .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "persistence.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "META-INF/beans.xml")
            .addAsResource(new File("src/test/resources/csman.properties"), "csman.properties");

}
```

So, the injected bean is the Configuration.class. First, I thought there was some initialization error in the Configuration impl class, so I created the @Bogus and BogusBean to only test the injection. I get the same errors.

```
@Bogus
public class BogusBean {

    public void setIt(){
    }
}
```

And the Qualifier

```
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Bogus {
}
```

And the injection in the EmailService (a @stateless session bean).

```
@Inject
@Bogus
private BogusBean bogus;

@EJB
private EmailRepository emailRepos;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    bogus.setIt();
}
```

The NPE happens on the bogus.setIt() line. as bogus == null.

This is the maven config

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I added a Profile for the glassfish embedded

```
<profile>
        <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2.2</version>
                <!--  was 4.0 -->
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.23.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>2.23.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

I also tried to change from weld-ee to weld-se but then the container doesn't even start. (as stated here) : [how-to-test-ejb-method-call-with-arquillian-weld-ee-embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667930/how-to-test-ejb-method-call-with-arquillian-weld-ee-embedded)

Comment: any solution for this? I have the same problem